.NET Generic host, exit if connection string is empty during configuration
I'm working on a console app using the .NET 8 generic host, I need some connection string for my database and I would like the app to not even start if these are missing.
This is my code right now, if connection strings are missing I'm logging the error and throw so the application doesn't start. This throw doesn't feel right to me, is there a better way to handle this situation ?
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
{
    logger.Info("Version: " + typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version);

    //Connection strings configuration
    var connectionString = ctx.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
    var connectionStringLog = ctx.Configuration.GetConnectionString("log_db");

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
    {
        logger.Error("db connection string missing");
        throw new Exception("db connection string missing");
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringLog))
    {
        logger.Error("log db connection string missing");
        throw new Exception("log db connection string missing");
    }

    services.AddRepositories(connectionString);
    services.AddLogRepositories(connectionStringLog);
    services.AddApplicationCoreServices();
}).Build();

try
{
    await host.RunAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error($"Host Run error: {ex.Message}");
}


That's more of a philosophical question but in my opinion your approach is just fine. You could add exit codes (0 for success and -1 when an error occurred) to make it behave like any other console app but that's not really a must.
